# How to make specific radio button in HTML5 with automatically selecting Specify while manually adding data

Tags: html, forms, frontend, web-frontend

I am working on a web interface for taking inputs in such a way that imagine there are three radio buttons with specific functions,and one of radio input function also has number input along with it. Take a look at example:

```
<h2>How many cars you own?</h2>

<form>
<input type="radio" name="car" checked>One<br>
<input type="radio" name="car">Two<br>
<input type="radio" name="car">Specify
<input type="number" name="car"><br>
</form>
```

Actually this works, but I want my website to be a little more smart and dynamic, so the **main problem is the moment I select a number from Choose, it should automatically mark the Specify radio button, but it doesn't**.And if I am choosing One or Two as my choice, it should disable the number input with a blank interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```js
var cars = document.getElementsByName("car");

cars[3].addEventListener("input", function(e) {

  if (e.target.value < 1) {
    e.target.value = 1;
  }

  if (e.target.value === 1) {
    cars[2].checked = true;
  } else {
    cars[e.target.value - 1].checked = true;
  }

});
```

```html
<h2>How many cars you own?</h2>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="car" checked>One<br>
  <input type="radio" name="car">Two<br>
  <input type="radio" name="car">Specify
  <input type="number" name="car" value="1"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want. In this code if user click on the field to input number, the specify radio input will be checked and when the user change the field number it will check the radio input that is related to the field number for example if he put 2 it will chedk the second radio button,

Comment: re-run the code and increase the number(use the increment and decrement arrows button), there's a bug

Comment: I edited the code but if you want the specify be checked when you focus on the field you should use checkbox instead, Is this what you wanted?

Comment: In the code above when I run I can write the number and it works, do you want to write something other than a number if so you should use type="text" input.

Comment: i cant enter number 5

Comment: and numbers greater than 5

Comment: you don't have 5 input thereis only 3 radio input and 1 input field you can only specify as many input as you have

Comment: If of all thanks for answering, actually, the third option means when you have more than two cars like 4,5,6 or more, we should specify ourselves.